# Unity Events from Animations are not getting triggered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm using an Animator to animate the player, and an Animation Blend to transition from different walking animations.
Now, I wanted to add walking SFX to the player. I saw ressources online about the Animations Events, so I tried to implement them. Now the thing is, the events are not getting triggered, and I don't understand why.

So, my player looks like this :

[image: The Player's GameObject]

And here is the PlayerModel, containing the script for the SFX :

[image: The PlayerModel Inspector]

The AnimationEvent looks like this for **every animation** (I doubled checked typos and such) :

[image: The AnimationEvent]

And the script (so the script you see on the PlayerModel) contains this function :

```
public class PlayerWalkSFX : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource playerWalkAudioSource;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] carpetStepClips = default;

    public void Step()
    {
        Debug.Log("Get called");

        playerWalkAudioSource.PlayOneShot(GetRandomAudioClip());
    }

    private AudioClip GetRandomAudioClip()
    {
        return carpetStepClips[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, carpetStepClips.Length)];
    }
}
```

Now, I've only saw that the script needs to be on the same GameObject, the function properly named and there you go. But they are not triggered, and I don't understand why. If you need more infos, I can send more.

Comment: not solving your issue but in general note that the upper bound of `Random.Range` for the `int` variant is **exclusive** meaning currently you will always ever only return the clip with index `0` .. it should rather be `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, carpetStepClips.Length)`

Comment: Oh thanks, since it was not working I did not see that. I'll edit my code, thanks again !

Comment: Are the events triggered if you move them to the beginning of the timeline?

Comment: @shingo They're not. I tested it right now.

Comment: Have you tried adding a parameter `Step(float f)`?

Comment: @shingo Same, the method is not getting called.

Comment: did you assign it?

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, I did. I put Step(float f) and used it under it with a "Debug.Log(f)". Checked the Event, saw that it was not required to toggle anything else. Entered PlayMode, walked straight forward and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if someone stumbles upon this post, just know that I asked to devs IRL too, and they checked my project.
There was no solution, since the problem was impossible to understand, and they had the same years prior. They simply stopped using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script and implementation seems to be fine. Try assigning the script to the object parameter of the event and see if it works.

Comment: The events are not getting triggered. Ain't the object parameter supposed to be what you give the function anyway ?

Comment: The Object parameter is used to call the function, if the animation and the script are not on the same game object. Did you by any chance leave a space after the function name in the event?

Comment: I double checked and asked my mates too (in case I'm an idiot), but no. Only "Step". I'm beginning to question the AnimationEvent system since I cannot for the life of me see what is the source of this problem. I saw posts about frames getting skipped if you use a BlendTree, but it's unlikely since my events are on random frames.

Comment: May be the animation isn't playing till it reached the event. may be it's transitioning to a different animation clip.

Comment: How can I check that it's transitionning ? I'm not the one who did the set up of the BlendTree so the mistake may be from here.